# How to generate a perfect cube map?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, images, layout

Ok, Ive found many T shaped cube map generators online, however I have a Unity game wherein I need a linear cube map for a skybox, like this in the bottom left:

[image]

Ive done this using a skybox I already had, and I have my custom images exported, however I have 2 seams that are imperfect, no matter what I do.

How can I generate a LINEAR cube map from 6 images perfectly?

Comment: You stack them on top of eachother, use imagemagic

Comment: I do not understand what relation either Photoshop or Illustrator have to this question.

Comment: Are your T shaped map's seams correct? If they are; I do not see why they would not work as linear.

Comment: @Scott, Photoshop and Illustrator can both edit and produce images in the manner requested.  For example, different images (or vectors) can be lined up in a linear fashion using move tools in each respective software package.  Each image can even be placed on a different layer to keep organized.

Comment: @SO_fix_the_vote_sorting_bug  I am *fully aware* of how both Photoshop and Illustrator function `:)` My comment eluded to the fact that the question contains *no information* about what specific application "blue" may be using nor what difficulty he/she/they are directly facing. There's *no useful information* in the question which could garner effective answers. Tags appear to just be "thrown on" without any consideration.

Comment: My comment was a "nudge" to try and gain more information. It clearly failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not expert in generating cubes map but maybe this helps you https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Cubemaps I've tried to make also cubes for the portfolio for [Animation Monster](https://animationmonster.us/) but some online website are generated it automatically.